# Permutation invariant binary codes

Tags: binary

I'm currently working on a problem where I have objects trivially numbered using a binary code. ie object 0 = 000, object 1 = 001, object 2 = 010 ... However, in my case I sometimes don't know where the start of the sequence is (ie 001 could appear as 010 or 100). Is there some optimal way that I can number my objects so that the labels are invariant to permutation? And what are the search terms I need to read up more about this myself?

An obvious solution would be to number them by the number of hot bits (ie 0=0000, 1=0001, 2=0011, 3=0111 ...) but this is a very inefficient code.

Comment: This question is unclear. If you are numbering the objects, surely you can decide to start the sequence at 0? I suspect this has to do more with  things like [prefix-free codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code). But "permutation" makes little to no sense in the context of such codes.

Comment: To give some context, I receive only a sequence of 1's and 0's which serve as an ID to which object sent the signal. Each object is constantly sending such a sequence, so I don't know where the beginning and end of each sequence is. Basically I have an arduino with some sensors attached.

Comment: That still omits a crucial detail: do you have the first bit of the whole sequence? Because if you have all bits'a prefix-free code is sufficient. You can then unambiguously decode the first symbol, and determine where the second symbol starts. But if you can miss an unknown amount of bits from the start, you need a self-synchronizing code.

Comment: I have all bits. So I guess a Huffman code or something will do. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the updated comments, a prefix-free code is sufficient. This will allow you to uniquely determine each symbol length. This solves the problem with not knowing where the next symbol starts.

Note that all fixed-length codes are trivially prefix-free. Just consider 8 bits ASCII: every 8 bits a new character starts, and each byte in the stream uniquely represents one ASCII character. The unique prefix length is exactly the fixed length.

There's a trivial conversion from any variable-length encoding that also would work here, despite not being prefix-free. Simply replace the start of each code with "11", each 0 bit with "01", each 1 bit with "10" and the end of each code with "00".   Now "00" becomes "11 01 01 00" and "000" becomes "11 01 01 01 00". To parse this, you look for '11...00" to find the symbol boundaries, and then simply decode the bits in between. Depending on the exact stream/message layer, you might even be able to skip the "00".